# Shell command to find width of a text rendered with some font

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, fonts

I need to find the width, in pixels, of a string displayed with some font. I know that I can do:

```
dzen2-textwidth \
   -adobe-times-medium-r-normal--8-80-75-75-p-44-iso8859-1 \
   "A Tale of Two Cities"
```

(this command comes from the `dzen2` package)

However, this doesn't support Xft. I want to be able to use the Xft font format, like "Droid Sans:size=12".

Is there a program that let me do this?

(It goes without saying that it should support Unicode, because I'm not using English. But I guess that anything that supports Xft is modern enough to support Unicode.)

I understand that I could write a program myself (using Ruby / Python / Haskell / NodeJS) if I have GTK/Pango/Whatever bindings, but first I want to see if there's a ready made program (A program in C/C++ is always better for me as I'm using a relatively slow computer and for scripts there's a long starting time (for this reason, BTW, Java is out of the question).

Comment: Perhaps you just need a more recent version of dzen2. According to its home page on github, https://github.com/robm/dzen/wiki, Xft support is optional; the default config.mk file (https://github.com/robm/dzen/blob/master/config.mk) has it enabled. You could always try downloading the source and building it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xft library has several `XftTextExtents*` functions for computing font metrics. All you need is to open a desired font & pass an address of `XGlyphInfo` structure to `XftTextExtentsUtf8()` function.

The following is the simplest possible program that does it. You run it like:

```
$ ./xft_str_width "Droid Sans:size=12" "A Tale of Two Cities"
174
```

To compile it, type:

```
cc xft_str_width.c -o xft_str_width `pkg-config --cflags x11 xft freetype2` `pkg-config --libs x11 xft freetype2`
```

The program:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <X11/Xft/Xft.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(getenv("DISPLAY"));
  if (!dpy) errx(1, "failed to open display %s", getenv("DISPLAY"));
  if (argc != 3) errx(1, "usage: xft_str_width font text-string");

  XftFont *font = XftFontOpenName(dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy), argv[1]);
  if (!font) errx(1, "no font match");

  XGlyphInfo info;
  XftTextExtentsUtf8(dpy, font, (FcChar8*)argv[2], strlen(argv[2]), &info);
  printf("%d\n", info.xOff);
}
```

More about `XGlyphInfo` structure & Xft library APIs in general can be read [here](https://www.keithp.com/%7Ekeithp/render/Xft.tutorial).